# Deploy .NET winforms application packaged with .Net Framework

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, .net-4.0, native

I have a Winforms application developed in `c#` targetting `.Net Framework 4.0`. I created a setup for the application and packaged the `.Net Framework 4.0` within the setup. During installation, the setup installs the `.Net Framework 4.0` (if not installed already), and the application works fine.

1. I know it's not possible to run `.Net` application without `.Net Framework`. Is there some way I can package the `CLR`, `JIT`, and all required `dll's` with my application so that I won't need to install the entire `.Net Framework 4.0` on the target machine?
2. Can i create my own installer for `.Net Framework 4.0`? Installer which insalls only the libraries which are required for my application, thus eliminating the need to install entire `.Net Framework`?

I have looked into `ngen`, Turbo Studio etc. to containerize the application but that does not suit for my purpose. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can change the `Copy Local` to `true`, for all your references.

Comment: i am talking about the dependencies inside .net framework on which my application relies. Even if i copy them, it still needs JIT to run.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework was not designed to be deployed partially. I don't think this is possible - even if you will get that to work, it won't be supported officially. You might even see that your app is running but it might crash at any time later as soon as an assembly gets referenced (lazy by reflection, for example) you have no direct reference to.

Having only those parts of the framework deployed which are directly or indirectly referenced by your app is one of the main ideas of .NET Core - but you won't be able to do full-featured UIs with it by now.